# Validation Symfony2 with query to database

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, callback

I have a problem with a validation form in symfony2.

I have a form with entity. Into the file 'validation.yml' I used CALLBACK: it invoke the method 'isValidForm' content in file 'Entity.php'

```
ALM\CreateReleaseBundle\Entity\createReleaseEntity:
    constraints:
        - Callback:
            methods: [isFormValid]
```

This is my file 'Entity.php'

```
<?php
namespace ALM\CreateReleaseBundle\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

class createReleaseEntity {
    protected $area;
    protected $relName;

    public function getArea() {
        return $this->area;
    }

    public function setArea($area) {
        $this->area = $area;
    }

    public function getRelName() {
        return $this->relName;
    }

    public function setRelName($relName) {
        $this->relName = $relName;
    }

    public function isFormValid(ExecutionContext $context) {
        // Validate Form
    }
}
```

Now in 'isFormValid' I would like to insert a forward to the function getRelease placed in another controller.

```
public function getReleaseAction (Request $request) {
$area = $request->get('area');
    $relName = $request->get('relName');
    $ret = $this->getRelease($area,$relName);
    $session = $this->get('request')->getSession();
    $session->set("releaseObj", $ret);
    return new Response ();
}
```

It is possible? How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not access the Controller from the Model under any circumstances.

What kind of query do you want to perform?

If you want to check if the Release is unique in database by relName for instance, use the Doctrine's UniqueValidator on that field.

Hope it helps